# Extension of publish transaction details info

Tags: web8.5, cme, gui-extensions

On our project we want to extend publish transaction details info in a way that you can see on the image below, in red frame:

[image: desired result]

My question is, is it possible and if yes what we should extend to achieve this. On the image below you can find options:

[image: Gui extension options]

Is this a List? Tabpages?

**If this is not possible, at least not in this way, what should we do?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To extend publish transaction details, your GUI extension needs to extend the following JavaScript and ASPX files:

- **%Tridion Home%\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Views\Popups\PublishTransaction\PublishTransaction.aspx**
- **%Tridion Home%\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Views\Popups\PublishTransaction\PublishTransaction.js**

So you can copy the above files in your extension and update the files. So in the extended PublishTransaction.aspx file in your extension, you would have to add the extra details that you want to be displayed in the publish transaction.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="New Data" />:
    </td>
    <td id="NewData">
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the extended PublishTransaction.js file in your extension, select the element with ID "NewData" like so `fields.NewData = $("#NewData");`  in the `initialize` method. And add the custom logic to set the value for the NewData element in the `transactionItemLoaded` method.

```
$dom.setInnerText(fields.NewData, "New Data Value");
```

Now all you have to do is configure the `extensiongroups` and `groups` in the config file properly so the extended JavaScript and ASPX files are loaded.

Comment: It should be noted that this way you customize built-in product Views; this is not really a modular UI extension and you will loose any such customizations if you upgrade the product.